# ¿Para que sirve el FileStream?

Tags: c#

Estaba repasando mis clases de C# cuando me encontré con esto

```
        SaveFileDialog f = new SaveFileDialog();
        f.Filter = "Archivo de Texto (.txt)|*.txt";
        if (f.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(f.FileName);
            w.Write(txtBlock.Text);
            w.Close();
        }
```

Y recordé que una vez mi profesor uso el FileStream

```
        SaveFileDialog f = new SaveFileDialog();
        f.Filter = "Archivo de Texto (.txt)|*.txt";
        if (f.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            FileStream s = new FileStream(f.FileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);                
            StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(s);
            w.Write(txtBlock.Text);
            w.Close();
        }
```

Y quisiera saber cual es la diferencia entre usarlo o no.

PSDT: Este codigo lo uso de ejemplo para crear un block de notas básico

Comment: Quiero añadir que de las dos maneras me funcional igual

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Son diferentes formas de hacer lo mismo, solo que usas un constructor diferente del StreamWriter segun que datos tengas

Si tienes el nombre del archivo pasaras ese por parametros, no se si conocias que puedes acceder al codigo del `net framework` para analizarlo por dentro

[StreamWriter Resource Code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamwriter.cs,9e38cb1c84769eba)

veras como al pasar solo la ruta este dentro crea un `FileStream`, solo que la clase lo hace por ti para que no tengas que escribir el codigo si es que tienes la ruta al archivo

Puede haber otros casos donde generes un documento en memoria por lo que tendras un `MemoryStream`, en este caso no hay una ruta fisica al archivo, este hereda de Stream, igual como lo hace el `FileStream`